# Example $4.8$ - Chapter $0$ - Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I have some doubts about the proof in example $4.8$ in chapter $0$ of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry book concerning to the part of the proof that the canonical projection of a differentiable manifold $M$ in it's quotient space $M/G$ given by the relation defined by an properly discontinuous action is a local diffeomorphism. Precisely, I didn't understand the following statement:

> Let $p_1 = (\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2) (p_2)$. Then $p_1$ and $p_2$ are equivalent in $M$, hence there is a a $g \in G$ such that $gp_2 = p_1$. It follows easily that  the restriction $(\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2)|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$ coincides with the diffeomorphism $\varphi_g|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$.

Why $(\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2)|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$ coincides with the diffeomorphism $\varphi_g|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$? How the fact that the action is properly discontinuous is used here to ensure that the functions coincide on $\textbf{x}_2(W)$? Is $G$ the group of $\textbf{all}$ diffeomorphisms of $M$ or just a group of a $\textbf{specific}$ diffeomorphisms of $M$?

About my last question, I think $G$ is the group of $\textbf{all}$ diffeomorphisms of $M$, because he stated that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are equivalent.

Below, there is the example $4.8$.

> $4.8$ Example. ($\textit{Discontinuous action of a group}$). We say that a group $G$ acts on a differentiable manifold $M$ if there exists a mapping $\varphi: G \times M \rightarrow M$ such that
>
> (i) For each $g \in G$, the mapping $\varphi_g: M \longrightarrow M$ given by $\varphi_g(p) = \varphi(g,p)$, $p \in M$, is a diffeomorphism and $\varphi_e = \text{identity}$.
>
> (ii) If $g_1, g_2 \in G$, $\varphi_{g_1g_2} = \varphi_{g_1} \circ \varphi_{g_2}$.
>
> Frequently, when dealing with a single action, we set $\varphi(g,p) = gp$; in this notation, condition $(ii)$ can be interpreted as a formof associativity: $(g_1g_2)p = g_1(g_2p)$.
>
> We say that the action is $\textit{properly discontinuous}$ if every $p \in M$ has a neighborhood $U \subset M$ such that $U \cap g(U) = \emptyset$ for all $g \neq e$.
>
> When $G$ acts on $M$, the action determines an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $M$, in which $p_1 \sim p_2$ if and only if $p_2 = gp_1$, for some $g \in G$. Denote the quotient space of $M$ by this equivalence relation by $M / G$. The mapping $\pi: M \longrightarrow M/G$, given by
>
> $$\pi(p) = \text{equiv. class of} \ p = Gp$$
>
> will be called the $\textit{projection}$ of $M$ onto $M/G$.
>
> Now let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and let $\varphi: G \times M \longrightarrow M$ be a properly discontinuous action of a group $G$ on $M$. We are going to show that $M/G$ has a differentiable structure with respect to which the projection $\pi: M \longrightarrow M/G$ is a local diffeomorphism.
>
> For each $p \in M$ choose a parametrization $\textbf{x}: V \longrightarrow M$ at $p$ so that $\textbf{x}(V) \subset U$, where $U \subset M$ is a neighborhood og $p$ such that $U \cap gU = \emptyset$, $g \neq e$. Clearly $\pi|_U$ is injective, hence $\textbf{y} = \pi \circ \textbf{x}: V \longrightarrow M/G$ is injective. The family $\{ (V,\textbf{y}) \}$ clearly covers $M/G$; for such a family to be a differentiable structure, it suffices to show that given two mappings $\textbf{y}_1 = \pi \circ \textbf{x}_1: V_1 \longrightarrow M/G$ and $\textbf{y}_2 = \pi \circ \textbf{x}_2: V_2 \longrightarrow M/G$ with $\textbf{y}_1(V_1) \cap \textbf{y}_2(V_2) \neq \emptyset$, then $\textbf{y}_1^{-1} \circ \textbf{y}_2$ is differentiable.
>
> For this, let $\pi_i$ be the restriction of $\pi$ to $\textbf{x}_i(V_i)$, $i = 1,2$. Let $q \in \textbf{y}_1(V_1) \cap \textbf{y}_2(V_2)$ and let $\textbf{r} = \textbf{x}_2^{-1} \circ \pi_2^{-1}(q)$. Let $W \subset V_2$ be a neighborhood of $\textbf{r}$ such that $(\pi_2 \circ \textbf{x}_2)(W) \subset \textbf{y}_1(V_1) \cap \textbf{y}_2(V_2)$. Then, the rstriction to $W$ is given by
>
> $$\textbf{y}_1^{-1} \circ \textbf{y}_2|_W = \textbf{x}_1^{-1} \circ \pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2 \circ \textbf{x}_2.$$
>
> Therefore, it is enough to show that $\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2$ is differentiable at $p_2 = \pi_2^{-1}(q)$. Let $p_1 = \pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2 (p_2)$. Then $p_1$ and $p_2$ are equivalent in $M$, hence there is a $g \in G$ such that $gp_2 = p_1$ . It follows easily that the restrinction $\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$ coincides with the diffeomorphism $\varphi_g|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$, which proves that $\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2$ is differentiable at $p_2$, as stated.

Thanks in advance!

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

I think that I finally understood the confusion that I did in the comments of Paul's answer, I thought that $\pi(gp) = \pi(p)$ because $gp = p$, but is not it. I will comment why $\pi(gp) = \pi(p)$ just for future reference if I forget this. Remember that

> $$\pi(p) = \text{equiv. class of} \ p = Gp$$

In other words,

$$\pi(p) = \text{equiv. class of} \ p = Gp = \{ gp \ ; \ g \in G \}.$$

This implies that $p, gp \in Gp$ because $p = ep$ and $e, g \in G$, i.e.,

$$\pi(p) = \text{equiv. class of} \ p = \text{equiv. class of} \ gp = \pi(gp).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G$ is *any* group acting by diffeomorphisms on $M$. The points $p_1, p_2$ are equivalent simply because both are mapped by $\pi$ to $q \in M/G$.

The claim that $(\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2)|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)} = \varphi_g|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$ is potentially false for the set $W$ considered by do Carmo. However, it is true if $W$ is chosen *carefully*.

Given $q \in \textbf{y}_1(V_1) \cap \textbf{y}_2(V_2)$, let $p_i = \pi_i^{-1}(q) \in \textbf{x}_i(V_i)$. Since $\pi(p_i) = q$, these two points are equivalent which means that there exists $g \in G$ such that $gp_2 = p_1$. Choose a neighborhood $U_2$ of $p_2$ in $M$ such that $\varphi_g(U_2) \subset \textbf{x}_1(V_1)$ and let $V'_2 = \textbf{x}_2^{-1}(U_2)$ which is an open subset of $V_2$ containing $\textbf{r} = \textbf{x}_2^{-1}(p_2)$. Now let $W \subset V'_2$ be an open neighborhood of $\textbf{r}$ such that $(\pi_2 \circ \textbf{x}_2)(W) \subset \textbf{y}_1(V_1) \cap \textbf{y}_2(V_2)$.

Then $(\pi_1^{-1} \circ \pi_2)|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)} = \varphi_g|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$ is equivalent to $\pi_2|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)} = \pi_1 \circ \varphi_g|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$. Note that the composition on the right hand side makes sense because we constructed $W$ such that $\varphi_g(\textbf{x}_2(W)) \subset \varphi_g(\textbf{x}_2(V'_2)) = \varphi_g(U_2) \subset \textbf{x}_1(V_1)$.

But now we have for $p \in \textbf{x}_2(W)$
$$(\pi_1 \circ \varphi_g)(p) = \pi(gp) = \pi(p) = \pi_2(p) .$$

Comment: What is $\pi(g)$ and where it was used that the action is properly discontinuous?

Comment: $\pi(g)$ was a typo which I have corrected. That the action is properly discontinuous enters a the very beginning of the prroof: $U$ was chosen such that $U \cap gU = \emptyset$ for all $g \ne e$.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this stupid question. How do you know that $\pi(gp) = \pi(p)$ if the $g$ is not arbritrary and, therefore you can choose and $g$, which acts on the diffeomorphisms of $M$ such that $g(\textbf{x}_2(W)) = \textbf{x}_2(W)$?

Comment: $\pi : M  \to M/G$ identifies all points which are equivalent under the action of $G$. We have $p \sim p'$ if and only if there exists $g \in G$ such that $p' = gp$. This explains why $\pi(gp) = \pi(p)$, and it is true for *any* $g$. Since $\pi(p_1) = \pi(p_2) = q$, we know that $p_1 \sim p_2$, that is, there exists a $g \in G$ such that $gp_2 = p_1$. This $g$ is not necessarily uniquely determined, but it is not arbitrary. For this $g$, $W$ was constructed so that $g\mathbf{x}_2(W) \subset \mathbf{x}_1(V_1)$. Then in fact $\pi_2|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)} = \pi_1 \circ \varphi_g|_{\textbf{x}_2(W)}$.

Comment: Ok, so if you ensure that $g(\textbf{x}_2(W)) \subset \textbf{x}_1(V_1)$ for some $g \in G$, then you ensure that there is $\tilde{p} \in \textbf{x}_1(V_1)$ such that $gp = \tilde{p}$ for some $p \in \textbf{x}_2(W)$, which confuse me is that you said that given $p \in \textbf{x}_2(W)$, exist some $g \in G$ such that $gp = p$, because $g(\textbf{x}_2(W)) \subset \textbf{x}_1(V_1)$, but this doesn't ensure that $gp = p$, but it ensures that $gp = \tilde{p}$ for some $\tilde{p} \in \textbf{x}_1(V_1)$.

Comment: George, I see that you are confused. But I do not have any idea how to explain it better than in my answer and in my comments. Try to follow the arguments step by step and tell me what is the *first* point where you get confused.

Comment: Dear @PaulFrost , thank you very much for the explanation, but I am in difficulty as well. Could you help me? First of all, why is there such an $U_2$ as you claim?

Comment: The map $\varphi_g(p) = \varphi(g,p) = gp$ is a diffeomorphism, in particular it is continuous. We have $\varphi_g(p_2) = gp_2 = p_1 \in \textbf{x}_1(V_1)$. This allows us to find $U_2$.

Comment: That is, we take the inverse image of a neighborhood of $p_1$?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin That is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand

Comment: @PaulFrost, I came back to your answer today and I think that I finally understood why $\pi(gp) = \pi(p)$. I edited my post and give details for this equality. Is my explanation there correct?

Comment: @George Yes, it is correct.